# Row_Number in SQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am looking for help using Row_Number in a trigger .

I’d like to create a trigger that populates a schedules table with a default set of tasks & days to complete the task.  The trigger is activated  when a new project is added to a ProjectDetails table (creating  ProjectID), and the default tasks/days are stored in a Defaults table.

The Default table looks like:

```
ID  |  Task | DaysForTask
```

The Schedule table(that gets updated by the trigger) looks like:

```
ID | ProjectID | Task | DaysForTask | ScheduleOrder | EstimatedDate
```

The Project Details table looks like:

```
ProjectID  | ProjectName | EngagementType
```

Once the Schedules table is set up, a user can enter a start date, and a separate function calculates the EstimatedDate for each task. The EstimatedDate is simply calculated as the date of the previous task + the DaysForTask for the current task, so its based on the order of the task. However, the order of the tasks could change from project to project or in the middle of the proejct, and so the function orders the tasks by the ScheduleOrder before returning the EstimatedDate, and the user can change the scheduleOrder as needed. But when the Schedule table is first created by this trigger, the ScheduleOrder is simply a row count.

So, after the addition of Project #18 to the Project Details table, the Schedule table should look like:

```
ProjectID   |   Task    |  DaysForTask    |  ScheduleOrder
18          |   TaskA   |        5        |       1
18          |   TaskB   |      10         |       2
```

I am trying to add the ScheduleOrder field using RowNumber.  The code below works fine without Row_Number, but it fails when I include Row_Number in it.  I don't get an error message, but the trigger isn't executed and the ProjectDetails table is not updated. Is there something wrong with this?

```
Delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `addProjMilestones` AFTER INSERT ON ProjectDetails
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       If NOT (new.EngagementType = 'Consulting') THEN
           INSERT INTO Schedule (ProjectID,Task,DaysForTask,ScheduleOrder) 
           SELECT   NEW.ProjectID,Task,DaysForTask,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RowNumber
           FROM Defaults; 
       end if;
  END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  Also explain what you want it to do.

Comment: I updated the initial question with more information. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: mysql version 5.6.41-84.1    ///   Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73    ///// phpMyAdmin  version 4.8.3